# Matlab 2015a and heavside()

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math

I've looked in the Matlab R2015a change log but can't seem to find any information.  Has the heaviside() function changed such integration results in the following answer:

```
>> int(heaviside(t),t)

ans =

(t*(sign(t) + 1))/2
```

This is not the same answer you would get in R2014a.  This also affects answers to ODE which use heaviside().  I don't doubt the answer is correct;  it's just more complicated in my mind than the R2014a result which returns:

```
>> int(heaviside(t),t)

ans =

t*heaviside(t)
```

Thanks!

Comment: The two expressions are equivalent. What's the problem?

Comment: @edgar.holleis: not for complex-valued inputs. At least in R2015a, [`sym/sign`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sign.html) is based on MuPAD's [`sign`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/sign.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two forms *are different* for complex-valued inputs. Additionally, the [`sym/sign`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/sign.html) function is a direct call to MuPAD's [`sign`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/sign.html), while [`sym/heaviside`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/heaviside.html) is not directly based on MuPAD's [`heaviside`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ref/heaviside.html), but does several manipulations and calls the lower-level undocumented `HeavisideAtOrigin` function (type `edit heaviside` in your Command Window to see the code).

It seems like your actual question is why the new version with `sign` doesn't work in other code that you didn't show. One workaround is to use the [`rewrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/rewrite.html) function to turn the output from `int` back into an expression in terms of the Heaviside function:

```
syms t
H = int(heaviside(t),t)
rewrite(H, 'heaviside')
```

which returns the expected `t*heaviside(t)`.

I don't know why this change was made, but I'd guess that it might be because there is no numeric floating-point version of `heaviside` while there is for `sign`. This might facilitate the conversion back and forth to symbolic math internally and for users unfamiliar with the Heaviside function.

Comment: Thanks, that does work.  This change is unfortunate.  This seems like it could quite a hassle going forward.  Any suggestions on how to raise this issue with Mathworks regarding a way to configure my environment to work the old way?

Comment: @xen: You're welcome. You can create a [service request](http://www.mathworks.com/company/aboutus/contact_us/?s_tid=gn_cntus) with the MathWorks and ask about this issue and any additional workarounds. If this answer was helpful, please [vote it up](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or even [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.